# Replacing issue for unlimited values in PHP

Tags: php

The code below is finding the `,-MI` and `,-AL` characters within `$l` and partially replace them with `Michigan` and `Alabama`. So if we have `$l = Montgomery,-AL` the code below returns `Montgomery,-Alabama` value for `$l`. But how to change this code to replace `Michigan` and `Alabama` with the whole value of `$l`.

```
<?php 
  $short = ["MI", "AL"];
  $long   = ["Michigan", "Alabama"];

  $newl = str_replace($short, $long, $l);
?>
<?php if (preg_match('(Michigan|Alabama)', $newl) === 1): ?>
  <p><?= $newl ?></p>
 endif; ?>
```

examples:
input: `$l = Alabaster,-AL`

output: `Alabaster,-Alabama`

desired output: `Alabama`

Comment: Could you provide any example with input + expected output? I have no clue what do you mean in your last sentence

Comment: See the example, now Alabama replaces with only AL but not with the Montgomery,-AL

Comment: Haven't you posted that before?

Comment: Got a dislike and one attacker here, is anyone here to actually want help?

Comment: So you want only `Alabama`  and remove the city completely?

Comment: yes, always when AL spotted within $l, I want AL to replace with the whole value of $l, Now it only replaces with AL: Montgomery,-Alabama which is not good

Comment: Is the state code always the last two letters of the string? Because just searching for `mi`, `al`, etc. in a string seems **very** unreliable to me.

Comment: ok, let's say searching `,-mi`, `,-al`

Comment: @Ray We can't see what `$l` looks like and the desire output is not that clear, do you think you could edit your question please and add $l + show us an example of what you want to get + what you get right now?

Comment: ok, i'll edit in 5min

Comment: are you talking about replacement in a string containing just one city and state code or can string contain multiple citys/states?  Is state code always uppercase as is usual? Are we just talking about AL & MI or others as well?

Comment: always upper case, not just AL & MI can be 52 other states as well, can be multiple cities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd create some kind of map with all states:

```
$states = [];
$states["AL"] = "Alabama";
$states["MI"] = "Michigan";
// add more if needed
```

You then need to extract the state code of your string somehow. Assuming it's always the last two letters, you could do something like this:

```
$l = "Montgomery,-AL";
$stateCode = substr($l, -2);
```

If that's not the case, you need to figure out yourself how to unambigously extract the state code.

After that you can simply access the full state name from your map by its code. See this [example](https://3v4l.org/2f1TQ).

In order to inject the state in your HTML only if the state code exists, you can use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
<?php if (array_key_exists($stateCode, $states)): ?>
  <p><?= $states[$stateCode] ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: could you please implement your code inside my code

Comment: i cant implement your code inside if. Could you please edit my code accordingly?

Comment: @Ray I added the HTML part that I've missed originally. This should put you in the right direction.

Comment: woooooooooooooooooooow

Answer (score 0):

In reply to my qn in your comments you said string can contain multiple cities.

This will convert state codes for single or multiple city/state strings and assumes you only want the state name to appear once e.g. "Texas" not "Texas-Texas" 
Note As an earlier edit of your qn indicated it was for use as a URL slug I've used '-' as a separator.

"Alabaster,-AL` will result in "Alabama".

"Alabaster,-AL;somecity,-MI,anothercity,-MI" will result in "Alabama-Michigan";

```
$code = array("MI" => "Michigan" , "AL" =>  "Alabama"); // etc
$newString = ''; // OR YOUR DEFAULT
$newStrSeparator = '-';
foreach($code as $short => $long) :
  if ( strpos($l, $short) !== false ){
$newString .=  $long .  $newStrSeparator;
  }
endforeach;
$newString = rtrim($newString, $newStrSeparator); // remove any trailing separator
if ($newString == '') { // if state not in string set it to whatever value you want }

echo $newString;
```

Comment: not multiple cities, I mean city name can be changed. You go too far. I don't understand your code now